# What is Causing these Memory Leaks in my Swift code?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, sprite-kit

Is there anyone who can tell my why my code is getting the following four memory leaks (as indicated below) and the code changes that need to be made to rectifiy it? It is a collectionNode I have created which has a dataSource and delegate and performing leak profiling indicates the four leaks.

[image]

```
weak var dataSource: CollectionNodeDataSource? { didSet{ setupData() } }

public func setupData() {

    let numberOfItems = dataSource!.numberOfItems() //LEAK 4bytes

    var j: Int = 0

    for i in numberOfCells/2..<numberOfCells {

        let item = dataSource!.collectionNode(self, itemFor: i) //LEAK 4bytes
        item.index = i
        item.id = j
        array_cells.append(item)
        j = j == numberOfItems-1 ? 0 : j+1

    }

    j = numberOfItems-1

    if array_cells[0].nameLabel != nil { cellHeight = array_cells[0].nameLabel!.frame.size.height } //LEAK 25bytes

    for i in (0...(numberOfCells/2)-1).reversed() {

        let item = dataSource!.collectionNode(self, itemFor: i)
        item.index = i
        item.id = j

        array_cells.insert(item, at: 0)
        j = j == 0 ? numberOfItems-1 : j-1

        cumultive_posY = cumultive_posY + cellHeight + spaceBetweenItems

    }

    for item in array_cells { itemNode?.addChild(item) } //LEAK 4bytes

    if currentIndex == -1 {

        currentIndex = numberOfCells/2

    } else {

        if let id = array_cells[currentIndex].id { currentIndex = (numberOfCells/2)+id }

    }

    biggestItem = array_cells.sorted{ $0.calculateAccumulatedFrame().size.height > $1.calculateAccumulatedFrame().size.height }.first! //LEAK 23b
    setSpacing()

    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in //LEAK 1 byte

        self?.snap(to: self!.currentIndex, withDuration: 0)
        self?.updateItemAppearance(aboutIndex: self!.currentIndex)
        self?.itemNode?.isHidden = false

    }

}

protocol CollectionNodeDataSource: class {

    func numberOfItems() -> Int
    func collectionNode(_ collection: CollectionNode, itemFor index: Index) -> CollectionNodeItem

}
```

The data model is as follows:

```
public class CapOptionsModel {

    static var `default`: CapOptionsModel = CapOptionsModel()

    let array_options = [ApetureCapSpinnerOption(mode: .liveStream, name: "Stream", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ButtonTip_LiveStream")),
    ApetureCapSpinnerOption(mode: .sessionCapture, name: "Capture", image:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "ButtonTip_SessionCapture"))]

    private init() {

    }

}
```

And the CollectionNodeItem is as like so:

```
class CollectionNodeItem: SKNode {

    fileprivate weak var collection: CollectionNode? { return self.parent as? CollectionNode }
    weak var nameLabel: SKLabelNode?
    weak var imageNode: SKSpriteNode?

    var id : Int!
    var index : Index!

    public override init() {

        super.init()
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        let nameLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: FONT_EUROEXT)
        addChild(nameLabel)
        self.nameLabel = nameLabel

        let imageNode = SKSpriteNode()
        addChild(imageNode)
        self.imageNode = imageNode

    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented") }


}
```

Comment: The code in the DispatchQueue is wrong (it shouldn't compile). All the references to 'self' need to be 'self?', because you're passing it into the closure as weak.

Comment: Yes, you are right, that shouldn't complie. I wrote it incorrectly. Have now corrected it to what I have in my code. Do you know how I can fix the leak in that DispatchQueue block at least?

Comment: Your code looks fine. If data is leaking, it's happening because of something happening in another part of your app. My *guess* is that dataSource isn't being deallocated. My strategy for hunting down leaks is to use the Allocations instrument, and in the lower left corner put in the name of your app to filter by its objects. Then look for objects that outlive their life-cycle. Once you know who's leaking, you can use Xcode's memory graph debugger feature to see what's holding references to the leaker. Good luck!